# Regex php - Match some escape characters inside attribute values

Tags: php, regex, xml

Well, basically I'm triying to match some escape characters inside some attributes ("name" & "author").

I'm working on a file uploader where one of the files which is uploaded is a .xml file.

Before parsing it to an XML Format, I'm trying to replace those characters with right format.
IE: `<` to `&lt;` or `'` to `&apos;` ...etc

These characters are inside single `'` quotes or double quotes `"`

The format of the raw data is:

```
<info name="Name containing ' apostrophe" author="Lower than < Character" ></info>
<info name='Name containing ' apostrophe' author='Lower than < Character' ></info>
```

The patter I have just tried is the following one

```
(name|author)="(\\\\[\\\\"]|[^\\\\"])*"[<|']
```

However it stopped matching content inside tags.

Comment: What's the context here? Unlike HTML, XML is neither expected nor allowed to be malformed. Why do you expect invalid XML in the first place?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Well, basically people upload their custom maps to my server, these maps are processed in LUA later and, these characters are allowed there (Probably the enviroment where are processed already transform them). But, In JS or PHP, Before parsing the raw data to an XML Object, these characters make the function to stop working properly when they are detected... I've got already the way to make it work which is to find the position where the character match by using PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE and replace it with my custom one. Obyously I will take care about the size of replaced character

Comment: If people creates maps by editing XML in notepad, you're going to find bigger problems than this. If you use a faulty preprocessor that damages data, I presume it's a third-party tool you don't control. Well, I don't have any answer but you have my sympathy :)

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Tha map in deep is not an .xml. The "map" is composed by some files like a .xml, few basic scripts for LUA and might some other files. This .xml only contains information about who made the map and which name is (name and author attributes, might some other few stuffs which I didn't add). I know you are right that people could alterate another attribute of any node, but this is already checked in another eviroment where LUA acts by itself. `NOTE` Data is not altered during upload comprobations, it is used to store name and prevent people from uploading it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regexp and application

```
$str = '<info name="Name containing \' apostrophe" author="Lower than < Character" ></info>
<info name='."'Name containing ' apostrophe' author='Lower than < Character' ></info>";

$regex = '@\s*
    (?:name|author)
    \=
    (?P<QUOTE>["\'])
    [^\'<>"]+
    (?P<CHAR>[\'<])
    [^>\'"]+
    (\k<QUOTE>)
    @misx';

echo preg_replace_callback($regex, 
    function ($matches) {
        switch ($matches['CHAR'][0]) {
            case "'":
                $matches['CHAR'][0] = '&apos;';
                break;
            case '<':
                $matches['CHAR'][0] = '&lt;';
                break;
        }
        return substr_replace($matches[0][0], $matches['CHAR'][0], $matches['CHAR'][1]-$matches[0][1], 1);
    },
    $str,
    -1,
    $count,
    PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE
);
```

result:

```
<info name="Name containing &apos; apostrophe" author="Lower than &lt; Character" ></info>
<info name='Name containing &apos; apostrophe' author='Lower than &lt; Character' ></info>
```

Look at https://3v4l.org/C9Vbd#v7.4.33